# Mongodb $rename creates new field but old field remains in document

Tags: database, mongodb, rename

Can you tell me please what am I doing wrong when I renaming document fields? I do it via command

```
db.events.update( { "ico": {$exists: false} }, { $rename: { 'icos': 'ico' } } )
```

The problem is that the old icos value remains in document. I dont understand why if we are talking about renaming. It maens rename not create new one and keep the old field.

Tanks.

Comment: Could you paste the document you're trying to update ?

Answer (score 0):

You doing everything is correct only one think. If you need to update more than one document please use `updateMany` extend `update`.

```
db.events.updateMany(
    {
        "ico": {
            $exists: false
        }
    }, 
    {
        $rename: { 
            "icos": "ico" 
        }
    } 
)
```